# QT drawing an ellipse or Triangle on a line with QGraphics

Tags: c++, qt, math, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

i draw multiple lines with

```
line = scene->addLine(x1, y1, x2, x2, Pen);
```

Now i want to add a label at the middle of the line(s) (for example a ellipse or a triangle. Ellipse is maybe the simple solution)

My idea was to calc a new point for Y (newY) and sub a length from x2.

`ellipse = scene->addEllipse(x2 - lengthX, newY, w, h, Pen, Brush);`

Calc newY:

> m = (x2 - x1) / (y2 -y1)
>
> newY = m * x2 - length + x2 -(m * y2)

But he draw the ellipse wrong.

How can i add the label? Am i on the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QLineF` class to help you out since it has some nice convenience methods.

First you can easily get the desired point along the line to draw your additional label/shape by using `QLineF::pointAt(param)` method.

In addition, if you would like to have your label/shape be oriented along the tangent you can use `QLineF::angle()`.

Comment: can u give me an example, how  to use QLineF::pointAt? how can i say he should point me my line?

Comment: For example, `QPointF midPoint = line.pointAt(0.5);` will give you the mid point of your line. (assuming line is a QLineF, if not you might have to convert it from QLine)

Comment: is it possible to locate the point in pixel? For example: pointAt(1) [100% = endpoint] - 20pixel?